# Why is the "Call" keyword required for methods of classes that take parameters?

Tags: excel, vba

My class has multiple methods. Some methods take parameters. Those methods require the keyword "Call" to work. Why?

```
MyObject.MyMethod   'Works just fine without Call.

Call MyObject.MyMethod(arg1, arg2)  'Requires Call. Won't compile without it.
```

Comment: It isn't. You can omit it if you don't use the parens:  `MyObject.MyMethod arg1, arg2`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Call` is never required. In fact it's been obsolete since the advent of *implicit call syntax* in... Visual Basic 4.0, if I recall correctly.

```
object.MemberName arg1, arg2
```

Notice the parentheses are gone. This would be illegal, as you noted:

```
object.MemberName (arg1, arg2)
```

Notice the whitespace between `MemberName` and the opening `(`: the VBE will always put a space there. That's the VBE saying "Ok so I'll take what's in these parentheses, evaluate that as an expression, and pass the result *by value* (regardless of the member's signature specifying `ByRef`, explicitly or not) to the member you're invoking". Except `(foo, bar)` isn't a legal expression, so the code doesn't compile.

When `MemberName` returns a value that the caller needs to capture, the parentheses behave differently:

```
foo = object.MemberName(arg1, arg2)
```

Notice there's no whitespace anymore; the VBE will remove it if you add any.

So with a more familiar and concrete example - note that it has nothing to do with objects & members:

```
MsgBox "Yes?", vbYesNo ' works fine
Call MsgBox("Yes?", vbYesNo) ' works fine
Call VBA.Interaction.MsgBox("Yes?", vbYesNo) ' works fine
MsgBox ("Yes?", vbYesNo) ' illegal
result = VBA.Interaction.MsgBox("Yes?", vbYesNo) ' works fine
```

The `Call` keyword only exists in VBA6/VBA7 for backward-compatibility purposes, like many, *many* other language constructs (`While...Wend` comes to mind). That's why [Rubberduck](http://www.github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck) (disclaimer: I'm one of the admins of that open-source project) flags its use as "obsolete", and provides tooling to remove it.

Answer (score 4):

@MathieuGuindon's answer covers the how part really well, so I thought I'd tackle the "why" part.

VB's syntax overloads the parentheses as a syntactical element. In the case of a procedure call, they are used to surround the [argument list](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee199407.aspx):

> ```
>  argument-list = [positional-or-named-argument-list] 
>  positional-or-named-argument-list = *(positional-argument ",") required-positional-argument 
>  positional-or-named-argument-list =/   *(positional-argument ",") named-argument-list 
>  named-argument-list = named-argument *("," named-argument)
> ```

Note that definition for an **Argument List** (5.6.13.1) falls under the category of **Index Expressions** ([5.6.13](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee199358.aspx)), and this isn't simply a misnomer, because the parser has to statically determine *what is being indexed*. This is complicated by the fact that `()` is also used for array indexing, and indexed member indexing.

The `Call` statement itself ([5.4.2.1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee200263.aspx)) consumes an argument list, but the fact that the parentheses can also be used as an indexer for a variable (arrays, etc.) means that there is the possibility that the expression to the right of `Call` can be ambiguous without the following rule:

> - If the **Call** keyword is specified:
>
>   - If a <call-statement> element’s referenced expression is an <index-expression>, the specified argument list is this expression’s argument list.
>   - Otherwise, the specified argument list is an empty argument list.

Forcing the use of the parentheses eliminates this ambiguity.  One example would be something like this:

```
Sub Foo()
    Dim Bar As Object
    Call Bar 1  '<-- What is Bar here? Is this the default member of the object, or the Sub?
    Bar 1  '<-- This in unambiguous, because ( ) are required to use a default member indexer.
End Sub

Sub Bar(paramater As Integer)
    'Do something
End Sub
```