# Converting ascending array sort to descending VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, sorting

I have this function that uses median of three method to sort a single dimension array in VBA, I tried to make it to sort descending, but somehow I am missing a part. Is there a simple way to achieve this?

```
Public Sub MedianThreeQuickSort1Desc(ByRef pvarArray As Variant, _
                                    Optional ByVal plngLeft As Long, _
                                        Optional ByVal plngRight As Long)

    Dim lngFirst As Long
    Dim lngLast As Long
    Dim varMid As Variant
    Dim lngIndex As Long
    Dim varSwap As Variant
    Dim a As Long
    Dim b As Long
    Dim c As Long

    If plngRight = 0 Then
        plngLeft = LBound(pvarArray)
        plngRight = UBound(pvarArray)
    End If

    lngFirst = plngLeft
    lngLast = plngRight
    lngIndex = plngRight - plngLeft + 1
    a = Int(lngIndex * Rnd) + plngLeft
    b = Int(lngIndex * Rnd) + plngLeft
    c = Int(lngIndex * Rnd) + plngLeft
    If pvarArray(a) <= pvarArray(b) And pvarArray(b) <= pvarArray(c) Then
        lngIndex = b
    Else
        If pvarArray(b) <= pvarArray(a) And pvarArray(a) <= pvarArray(c) Then
            lngIndex = a
        Else
            lngIndex = c
        End If
    End If

    varMid = pvarArray(lngIndex)
    Do
        Do While pvarArray(lngFirst) < varMid And lngFirst < plngRight
            lngFirst = lngFirst + 1
        Loop

        Do While varMid < pvarArray(lngLast) And lngLast > plngLeft
            lngLast = lngLast - 1
        Loop

        If lngFirst <= lngLast Then
            varSwap = pvarArray(lngFirst)
            pvarArray(lngFirst) = pvarArray(lngLast)
            pvarArray(lngLast) = varSwap
            lngFirst = lngFirst + 1
            lngLast = lngLast - 1
        End If
    Loop Until lngFirst > lngLast

    If (lngLast - plngLeft) < (plngRight - lngFirst) Then
        If plngLeft < lngLast Then MedianThreeQuickSort1 pvarArray, plngLeft, lngLast
        If lngFirst < plngRight Then MedianThreeQuickSort1 pvarArray, lngFirst, plngRight
    Else
        If lngFirst < plngRight Then MedianThreeQuickSort1 pvarArray, lngFirst, plngRight
        If plngLeft < lngLast Then MedianThreeQuickSort1 pvarArray, plngLeft, lngLast
    End If
End Sub
```

**Testing sub:**

```
Sub TryIt()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim arr As Variant

    arr = Array("Apple", "word", 4, "Jack", 521, "123", 1, 2, 3, 0)

    Call MedianThreeQuickSort1(arr)
    For i = 0 To UBound(arr)
        Debug.Print arr(i) & " "
    Next i
End Sub
```

**Output:**

```
0 
1 
2 
3 
4 
521 
123 
Apple 
Jack 
word
```

Comment: Maybe [this project](https://github.com/Senipah/VBA-Better-Array) can give you some ideas (they don't implement a descending sort but the algorithm is really impressive)

Comment: Friendly hint: call the sub procedure argument without brackets: `MedianThreeQuickSort1 arr` to preserve the `ByRef` accessibility. BTW Can you edit the working ascending sort code to see what and where you made changes in code?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was not that hard:

```
Public Sub MedianThreeQuickSort1_Desc(ByRef pvarArray As Variant, _
                                    Optional ByVal plngLeft As Long, _
                                        Optional ByVal plngRight As Long)

    Dim lngFirst As Long
    Dim lngLast As Long
    Dim varMid As Variant
    Dim lngIndex As Long
    Dim varSwap As Variant
    Dim a As Long
    Dim b As Long
    Dim c As Long

    If plngRight = 0 Then
        plngLeft = LBound(pvarArray)
        plngRight = UBound(pvarArray)
    End If

    lngFirst = plngLeft
    lngLast = plngRight
    lngIndex = plngRight - plngLeft + 1
    a = Int(lngIndex * Rnd) + plngLeft
    b = Int(lngIndex * Rnd) + plngLeft
    c = Int(lngIndex * Rnd) + plngLeft
    If pvarArray(a) <= pvarArray(b) And pvarArray(b) <= pvarArray(c) Then
        lngIndex = b
    Else
        If pvarArray(b) <= pvarArray(a) And pvarArray(a) <= pvarArray(c) Then
            lngIndex = a
        Else
            lngIndex = c
        End If
    End If

    varMid = pvarArray(lngIndex)
    Do
        Do While pvarArray(lngFirst) > varMid And lngFirst < plngRight
            lngFirst = lngFirst + 1
        Loop

        Do While varMid > pvarArray(lngLast) And lngLast > plngLeft
            lngLast = lngLast - 1
        Loop

        If lngFirst <= lngLast Then
            varSwap = pvarArray(lngLast)
            pvarArray(lngLast) = pvarArray(lngFirst)
            pvarArray(lngFirst) = varSwap
            lngFirst = lngFirst + 1
            lngLast = lngLast - 1
        End If
    Loop Until lngFirst > lngLast

    If (lngLast - plngLeft) < (plngRight - lngFirst) Then
        If plngLeft < lngLast Then MedianThreeQuickSort1_Desc pvarArray, plngLeft, lngLast
        If lngFirst < plngRight Then MedianThreeQuickSort1_Desc pvarArray, lngFirst, plngRight
    Else
        If lngFirst < plngRight Then MedianThreeQuickSort1_Desc pvarArray, lngFirst, plngRight
        If plngLeft < lngLast Then MedianThreeQuickSort1_Desc pvarArray, plngLeft, lngLast
    End If
End Sub
```

**Example:**

```
Sub TryIt()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim arr As Variant

    arr = Array("Apple", "word", 4, "Jack", 521, "123", 1, 2, 3, 0)

    Call MedianThreeQuickSort1_Desc(arr)
    For i = 0 To UBound(arr)
        Debug.Print arr(i) & " "
    Next i
End Sub
```

**Output:**

```
word 
Jack 
Apple 
123 
521 
4 
3 
2 
1 
0
```

Comment: Are you sure to get the above output? - Mine results in `Apple|word|4|Jack|521|123|1|2|3|0`. - BTW You could shorten code by `Debug.Print Join(arr, "|")` instead of a loop through each item :)

Comment: @T.M. 1- Yeah, I ran it again and I am getting what I have posted. Did you use the sub that has _Desc at the end of its name? I tried it with 3 different items and I am getting the right answer. 2- I wanted to copy paste the answer from the immediate window and have one item per line, `Join` is shorter, thanks though!

Comment: If a `Call` statement is specified, you *must* enclose argumentlist in parentheses. - Trying out your answer, I killed the `Call` statement as I don't use it, but *forgot* to remove the brackets for this direct call.  If a proc is used without `Call` but with parentheses, it's a dangerous thing as there can happen sort of evaluation (e.g. ranges) or a possible `ByVal` transformation of `ByRef` arguments. So a correct direct call is `MedianThreeQuickSort1_Desc arr` **without** parentheses to receive the same output ~> `word|Jack|Apple|123|521|4|3|2|1|0` and apologize myself :-)

Comment: FYI [Wyh is the call keyword required ...?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54368378/why-is-the-call-keyword-required-for-methods-of-classes-that-take-parameters/54369288#54369288), citation: *"Call is never required. In fact it's been obsolete since the advent of implicit call syntax in... Visual Basic 4.0, if I recall correctly."*

Comment: I always use `call`. If you don't need the output of a function you can use `call` and run the function. Using call helps to easily recognize the routine calls in code lines.